# How to customize Tailwind CSS height?

Tags: tailwind-css

I'm building a website in tailwind CSS. I'm new to it and I don't know how to customise the height. I want my image height to be exactly 40rem=640px. But the max height I could give in tailwind is 24rem 384px. How to go about it?

Answer (score 1):

You can provide custom height like this, `h-[40rem]`

Full example in React:`<img className="h-[40rem] text-white" src="http://src.com">`

Or in pure html: `<img class="h-[40rem] text-white" src="http://src.com">`